# How to stroke a grid of points relative to UIView size?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I'm trying to stroke an array of `UIBezierPath` as point grid on display. The spacing of the points would be relative to the size of the `UIView` , something like: `(bounds.UIView / 10)` to make the spacing 10 on each side

So basically I have two questions:

1) How to stroke a single point using `UIBezierPath`?

2) How to create an array of points and stroke them on a `UIView`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in **Swift 3**:

```
func addDashedLine(layer: CALayer, dotSize: CGFloat) {
    let  p0 = CGPoint(x: 0, y: layer.bounds.height/2)
    let  p1 = CGPoint(x: layer.bounds.width, y: layer.bounds.height/2)

    let  path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to:p0)
    path.addLine(to:p1)
    path.stroke()

    let stepLength = Float(layer.bounds.width/10.0)
    let dashPattern = [NSNumber(value: 0.001), NSNumber(value: stepLength)]

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.frame = layer.bounds
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = dotSize
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = dashPattern
    shapeLayer.lineDashPhase = dotSize
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

    layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

This example uses a simple path to draw a horizontal line. If you need to draw a line with a fixed amount of dots, you will need to calculate it's length first and then divide it by the number of dots you want to be drawn.

**Usage:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addDashedLine(layer: view.layer, dotSize: 3)
}
```

**Output:**

[image]